# IIS URL issue for a ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a hyperlink on my aspx which will take to users to

```
http://something/leadoc/FnJavaView.aspx?Library=DefaultIMS:myserver:FileNet&Id=3611376&ObjType=2&Op=View
```

I have the same link on another web application, when users click on that link it is showing something like below

```
http://something/leadoc/FnJavaView.aspx?Library=DefaultIMS%3amyserver%3aFileNet&Id=3611376&ObjType=2&Op=View
```

If you notice the ':' is converted to %3a

because of that URL is throwing an error.

Could you please help?

Comment: you have to use some kind of encoding in your url link.

Comment: What is the error? %3a would be the correct URL encoding for :. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: I have never seen a URL do anything, much less "throw an error". What is throwing an error, and what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the error is when the link is used from your ASPX you need to [URL encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) the URL

```
string url = "http://something/leadoc/FnJavaView.aspx?Library={0}&Id={1}&ObjType={2}&Op={3}";
string library = Server.UrlEncode("Server.UrlEncode");
int id = 3611376;
int objType = 2;
string op = Server.UrlEncode("View");

url = string.Format(url, new object[]{library, id, objType, op});
```

Any dynamic string data should be URL encoded in query string.

Comment: is there any IIS setting to allow this? This was working absolutely fine all this while. There is something changed in the IIS server